# SD card photos aren't displayed when attaching photos in WhatsApp/Hike

Tags: whatsapp, photos

Microsoft Lumia 535: I have all my photos and videos on the SD card, and they're all in albums in the Photos app. But when I try to attach photos/videos in WhatsApp/Hike, only a few albums get displayed (namely Whatsapp, Screenshots, Camera, Saved pictures). Thus none of my photos saved on SD card can be sent via WhatsApp/Hike. Please tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: Did you put these photos on the SD card using the phone, or were they already there? Does the photos app see them?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. Put all your image files in 'Pictures' folder on SD card (which gets created by default) and then everything will get displayed on Whatsapp etc.

Comment: Please *accept* your own answer.